# What shall I do to solve this error? ImportError: No module named requests.structures

Tags: python, scrapy, importerror

I'm trying to run a scrapy project in python 2.7 but I have that problem. I had other problems but solved them with `sudo pip install ...` I looked up in google but can't find any solution to this problem.

Comment: You need to share more details, a simple "I have an error" is hard to debug. Update your question with details, environment settings, stack error if you have it, possible solutions you've found but haven't solve it...

Answer (score 5):

Have you installed the [`requests`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) library?

```
sudo pip install requests
```

`requests.structures` is simply a module in that package.